How to efficiently solve the Maximum Product Subarray problem in Python?
I’m trying to solve the Maximum Product Subarray problem, which is described as follows:
Given an array of integers (positive, negative, or zero), find the maximum product of any contiguous subarray.
Example:
Input: [-2, 6, -3, -10, 0, 2]
Output: 180
Explanation: The subarray [6, -3, -10] gives the product 6 * -3 * -10 = 180.
I’ve tried iterating through the array while keeping track of the current maximum and minimum products, but I’m getting confused about how to handle cases where a negative number or zero appears.
def maxProduct(arr):
   max_ending_here = 0
   min_ending_here = 0
   max_so_far = 0

Not sure how to update max_ending_here and min_ending_here for negative numbers
    for num in arr:
        pass  # Implementation goes here

 return max_so_far

`
`Questions:

How should I handle the transition when encountering a negative number or zero in the array?
Is there a better way to handle this problem without considering all possible subarrays explicitly (which would take O(n²) or more)?
What is the optimal time complexity of solving this problem, and how can I ensure my approach achieves it?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!`

Considering the number with index x array[x], there are x + 1 possible continuous arrays ending with array[x]:
array[0 .. x]
array[1 .. x]
array[2 .. x]
...
array[x]

If we want to find the maximum product from these arrays, we need:
the maximum positive product of the continuous array ends with array[x-1] and the minimum negative product of the continuous array ends with array[x-1].
if array[x] is positive, the maximum product of continuous array ends with array[x] will be maximum positive product of continuous array ends with array[x-1] * array[x]
if array[x] is negative, the maximum product of continuous array ends with array[x] will be minimum positive product of continuous array ends with array[x-1] * array[x]
So we record the maximum positive product of the continuous array ending with array[x] and the minimum negative product of the continuous array ending with array[x] and iterate this array. This way, we get our O(N) time complexity solution.
One can easily prove O(N) is the optimal time complexity for this problem.
You can check my code for details:
def sol(array):
    min_number = None
    max_number = None
    max_ans = None
    for x in array:
        if x == 0:
            min_number = None
            max_number = None
            if max_ans is not None:
                max_ans = max(max_ans, x)
            else:
                max_ans = 0
        elif x > 0:
            if max_number is not None:
                max_number = max_number * x
            else:
                max_number = x
            if min_number is not None:
                min_number = min_number * x
        else:  # x < 0
            if max_number is not None and min_number is not None:
                min_number, max_number = max_number * x, min_number * x
            elif min_number is not None:
                max_number = min_number * x
                min_number = min(x, min_number)
            elif max_number is not None:
                min_number = max_number * x
            else:
                min_number = x
        if max_ans is None:
            if max_number is not None:
                max_ans = max_number
            if min_number is not None:
                max_ans = min_number
        else:
            if max_number is not None:
                max_ans = max(max_ans, max_number)
            if min_number is not None:
                max_ans = max(max_ans, min_number)
    return max_ans


print(sol([-2, 6, -3, -10, 0, 2]))
print(sol([-1, 0, -1]))
print(sol([-1, -3, -2]))
print(sol([0, -1, 1, 0, -1]))
print(sol([0, -1, -3, -2, 0, -1]))


Try print(sol([-1, 0, -1]))

@lastchance Thanks for your good example, I edited my code and now it outputs 0 for this case.

That's much better!

sol([7]*100000) takes ~1 second, sol([7]*200000) takes ~4 seconds. Doesn't seem O(N).

@nocomment Because the answer is getting bigger we can't consider multiplying as a constant time operation. If you can try sol([1]*1000000) and sol([1]*2000000) you will find it is a O(N) since the answer keeps small.

You actually don't have to bother about zero or negative values; for each new value x, just keep the widest range defined by (previous) minimum * x, (previous) maximum * x and x : this will "reset" the range if x == 0, and swap the min/max if x is negative.
def max_product(my_list):
    current_min = current_max = best = my_list[0]
    for x in my_list[1:]:
        current_min, current_max = min(current_min * x, current_max * x, x), max(current_min * x, current_max * x, x)
        best = max(current_max, best)
    return best


Following is the optimal solution code for Maximum Product SubArray Problem:
def maxProduct(arr):
if not arr:
    return 1e-9

max_ending_here = min_ending_here = max_so_far = arr[0]

for num in arr[1:]:
    candidates = (num, num * max_ending_here, num * min_ending_here)
    max_ending_here = max(candidates)
    min_ending_here = min(candidates)
    max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)

return max_so_far

Answers to your queries -

Encountering 0 and -ve number cases is handled by making a tuple of candidates, correspondingly max_ending_here (max product suffix) and min_ending_here (min product suffix) is updated. max_so_far (final result) is correctly updated at every step/iteration suitably. Encountering -ve number case is handled by maintaining the least -ve product suffix upto the current iterator.

Doing a single traversal over array arr, hence, it's a O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

Most optimal should be O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity only since it's a bare minimum. As you have to traverse at least every element of array arr once. O(1) space complexity because maintaining constant (3) no. of auxillary variables to solve the problem, 1 for final result and 2 for least and greatest product suffix upto the current iterator/step.



Recurse at "best so far"/0/rest of array if there is a zero.
Otherwise, test each cumulative product if an entry is positive or (cumulative product/first negative) if an entry is negative and there is a "first negative".
def sol( array ):
    N = len( array )
    best, first_negative, current = array[0], 1, 1                      # first_negative initialised to "no-damage"
    for i in range( N ):
        a = array[i]
        if a == 0: return max( best, 0 ) if i == N - 1 else max( best, 0, sol( array[i+1:] ) )   # recurse at zeros
        current *= a
        best = max( best, current, current // first_negative )
        if current < 0 and first_negative >= 0: first_negative = current
    return best


print(sol([-2, 6, -3, -10, 0, 2]))
print(sol([-1, 0, -1]))
print(sol([-1, -3, -2]))
print(sol([0, -1, 1, 0, -1]))
print(sol([0, -1, -3, -2, 0, -1]))
print(sol([0, -1, -3, -2, 0, -1, 0]))
print(sol([-3]))
print(sol([-3, 0]))

